# onChange event Function is Lagging In My React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onchange, html-input

In my react app on user register page am trying to check weather a username already exist or not my code is

```
checkUserName = (e) => {
this.setState({username:e.target.value});
let username = this.state.username;
db.collection("users").doc(username).get()
.then((snapshot)=>{
 if(snapshot.exists)
 {
   this.setState({usernameExistError:"show"}); *//this is classname of error div*
   this.setState({isUsernameOk:false})
   console.log(this.state.usernameExistError,this.state.isUsernameOk);
 }
 else
 {
   this.setState({usernameExistError:"hide"});
   this.setState({isUsernameOk:true})
   console.log(this.state.usernameExistError,this.state.isUsernameOk);
 }
 })
 }
```

all works fine when i check console.But   **The Problem is when i pressed a key in my input , state username is blank and when i type the second letter then the username state reads the first letter**.
so when an existing username is found only when the data is like "EXISTINGUSERNAME" + SOME_KEY_PRESS 
How can i solve this...Thanks In Advance

Comment: FYI `setState` is async and when you want to see the update on setstate instantly, you need to use callback, like `setstate({ key: updated_value},()=> console.log(this.state.key))`, now you can see the state update insteantly. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use the `state` at the moment when it is still old, since the `setState()` occurs asynchronously.

To solve your problem, you should set the value to a variable and use it in the future:

```
const { target: { value: username } } = e;

this.setState({ username });
db.collection("users").doc(username).get()

// ...the rest of code
```

Or perform all actions depending on the current state in the callback:

```
this.setState({ username: e.target.value }, () => {
  db.collection("users").doc(this.state.username).get()

  // ...the rest of code 
});
```

Example of `setState()` async behavior:

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: 1
  }
  
  onClick = () => {
    console.log(`data before set: ${this.state.data}`);
    
    const newData = this.state.data + 1;
    
    this.setState(
      { data: newData }, 
      () => console.log(`data in callback: ${newData}`)
    );
    
    console.log(`data after set: ${this.state.data}`);
    console.log(`actual current data: ${newData}`);
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.onClick}>Click Me!</div>;
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<TestComponent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
#app {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You..This works for me..But i doesn't understand how...Thank You so much

Comment: You need to understand the concept of synchronous and asynchronous code execution in javascript.